# Obter resultado de uma query, convertendo campo DataHora ao fuso-Horário local

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela no banco de dados sql server que possui o seguinte campo DataHora onde

tenho dados incluídos neste seguinte formato:

```
 DataHora
 2015-04-20 17:43:04.000
```

esse horário nao está ao formato do nosso fuso-Horário.

Preciso fazer uma query que no resultado me mostre o resultado Convertido ao nosso fuso-Horário

tenho a seguinte query:

```
  select Serial, 
 Latitude,
 Longitude,
 DataHora as DataHora
 from [CheckPoint] where DataHora between SWITCHOFFSET (CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2015-04-22 10:00'),'-03:00')and SWITCHOFFSET (CONVERT(datetimeoffset, '2015-04-22 11:00'),'-03:00')
 and serial='113394' order by DataHora
```

Teria alguma forma mais facil de obter esses dados convertidos ? na minha query estou passando uma certa data e está convertendo ao fuso indicado ou seja, o que eu digitar 
a hora vai está -3.
entao nao vou obter dados concretos da hora indicada.

Dúvida:
Preciso obter esses dados formatados ao nosso fuso-horário,por que as datas que irao ser passadas por parametros estao em fuso local

Comment: Está a usar apenas SQL ou está a utilizar outra linguagem para construir os parâmetros?

Comment: Cara c#! estou mostrando só a query,mas eu tenho um metodo na minha aplicação onde mando por parametro a DataHora

Comment: @HansMiller Já encontrou a solução?

Comment: Qual o problema em usar o `SWITCHOFFSET`?

Answer (score -1):

Veja se está instrução ajuda:

Comando:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),CAST('2015-04-20 17:43' AS datetime2),103)+' '+ CONVERT(varchar(8),CAST('2015-04-20 17:43' AS datetime2),114) AS 'data'
```

Resultado:

```
20/04/2015 17:43:00
```